# PostgreSQL master constantly demoted by pacemaker with repmgr

Tags: postgresql, replication, pacemaker

I'm in the process of setting up a PostgreSQL 9.2.8 cluster made of 2 nodes, one master, and one slave. I use streaming replication and repmgr 2.0. My platform is RHEL 6.3.

Master and slave can be started manually, but I can't have them started by my Pacemaker cluster. Logs show the master is started successfully, then the monitor returns a 8 (running as master), and then it is almost instantly demoted by pacemaker. On my second node, the slave doesn't start at all :

```
Apr 28 12:41:07 clustera lrmd: [1891]: info: RA output: (POSTGRESQL:0:start:stdout) POSTGRESQL : action = start
Apr 28 12:41:07 clustera lrmd: [1891]: info: RA output: (POSTGRESQL:0:start:stdout) START: status = 7
start() NOT RUNNING
Apr 28 12:41:07 clustera lrmd: [1891]: info: RA output: (POSTGRESQL:0:start:stdout) calling pg_start
Apr 28 12:41:07 clustera lrmd: [1891]: info: RA output: (POSTGRESQL:0:start:stdout) starting /usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_ctl start -w -D /opt/pgdata -l /var//ha/postgresql/postgres_ha.log -o '-c config_file=/opt/pgdata/postgresql.conf' -o '-p 5432'
Apr 28 12:41:08 clustera lrmd: [1891]: info: RA output: (POSTGRESQL:0:start:stdout) pg_start(): asked for start , waiting 10s
Apr 28 12:41:18 clustera lrmd: [1891]: info: RA output: (POSTGRESQL:0:start:stdout) pg_start(): asked for start, waited long enough
checing state
Apr 28 12:41:18 clustera lrmd: [1891]: info: RA output: (POSTGRESQL:0:start:stdout) in pg_state_check: 100
started as MASTER
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1892] clustera      attrd:   notice: attrd_trigger_update:     Sending flush op to all hosts for: master-pg92 (50)
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1892] clustera      attrd:   notice: attrd_perform_update:     Sent update 194: master-pg92=50
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1894] clustera       crmd:     info: abort_transition_graph:   te_update_diff:176 - Triggered transition abort (complete=0, tag=nvpair, id=status-clustera-master-pg92, name=master-pg92, value=50, magic=NA, cib=0.220.185) : Transient attribute: update
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1894] clustera       crmd:     info: process_lrm_event:        LRM operation POSTGRESQL:0_start_0 (call=105, rc=0, cib-update=192, confirmed=true) ok
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1894] clustera       crmd:     info: te_rsc_command:   Initiating action 41: notify POSTGRESQL:0_post_notify_start_0 on clustera (local)
Apr 28 12:41:18 clustera lrmd: [1891]: info: rsc:POSTGRESQL:0:106: notify
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1894] clustera       crmd:     info: te_rsc_command:   Initiating action 43: notify POSTGRESQL:1_post_notify_start_0 on clusterb
Apr 28 12:41:18 clustera lrmd: [1891]: info: RA output: (POSTGRESQL:0:notify:stdout) UNAME  === clustera
Apr 28 12:41:18 clustera lrmd: [1891]: info: RA output: (POSTGRESQL:0:notify:stdout) SUCCESS
Apr 28 12:41:18 clustera lrmd: [1891]: info: RA output: (POSTGRESQL:0:notify:stdout) POSTGRESQL : action = notify
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1894] clustera       crmd:     info: process_lrm_event:        LRM operation POSTGRESQL:0_notify_0 (call=106, rc=0, cib-update=0, confirmed=true) ok
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1894] clustera       crmd:   notice: run_graph:        ==== Transition 64 (Complete=21, Pending=0, Fired=0, Skipped=1, Incomplete=0, Source=/var/lib/pengine/pe-input-67.bz2): Stopped
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1894] clustera       crmd:   notice: do_state_transition:      State transition S_TRANSITION_ENGINE -> S_POLICY_ENGINE [ input=I_PE_CALC cause=C_FSA_INTERNAL origin=notify_crmd ]
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1893] clustera    pengine:   notice: unpack_config:    On loss of CCM Quorum: Ignore
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1893] clustera    pengine:  warning: unpack_rsc_op:    Processing failed op POSTGRESQL:0_last_failure_0 on clustera: master (8)
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1893] clustera    pengine:   notice: common_apply_stickiness:  MS_POSTGRESQL can fail 999987 more times on clustera before being forced off
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1893] clustera    pengine:   notice: common_apply_stickiness:  MS_POSTGRESQL can fail 999987 more times on clustera before being forced off
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1894] clustera       crmd:   notice: do_state_transition:      State transition S_POLICY_ENGINE -> S_TRANSITION_ENGINE [ input=I_PE_SUCCESS cause=C_IPC_MESSAGE origin=handle_response ]
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1894] clustera       crmd:     info: do_te_invoke:     Processing graph 65 (ref=pe_calc-dc-1398703278-318) derived from /var/lib/pengine/pe-input-68.bz2
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1894] clustera       crmd:     info: te_rsc_command:   Initiating action 9: monitor POSTGRESQL:0_monitor_60000 on clustera (local)
Apr 28 12:41:18 clustera lrmd: [1891]: info: rsc:POSTGRESQL:0:107: monitor
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1893] clustera    pengine:   notice: process_pe_message:       Transition 65: PEngine Input stored in: /var/lib/pengine/pe-input-68.bz2
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1892] clustera      attrd:   notice: attrd_trigger_update:     Sending flush op to all hosts for: master-pg92 (100)
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1892] clustera      attrd:   notice: attrd_perform_update:     Sent update 196: master-pg92=100
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1894] clustera       crmd:     info: abort_transition_graph:   te_update_diff:176 - Triggered transition abort (complete=0, tag=nvpair, id=status-clustera-master-pg92, name=master-pg92, value=100, magic=NA, cib=0.220.188) : Transient attribute: update
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1894] clustera       crmd:     info: process_lrm_event:        LRM operation POSTGRESQL:0_monitor_60000 (call=107, rc=8, cib-update=194, confirmed=false) master
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1894] clustera       crmd:  warning: status_from_rc:   Action 9 (POSTGRESQL:0_monitor_60000) on clustera failed (target: 0 vs. rc: 8): Error
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1894] clustera       crmd:  warning: update_failcount:         Updating failcount for POSTGRESQL:0 on clustera after failed monitor: rc=8 (update=value++, time=1398703278)
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1894] clustera       crmd:     info: abort_transition_graph:   match_graph_event:277 - Triggered transition abort (complete=0, tag=lrm_rsc_op, id=POSTGRESQL:0_last_failure_0, magic=0:8;9:65:0:70e313b8-b64a-4340-8d96-e64054ac9439, cib=0.220.190) : Event failed
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1894] clustera       crmd:   notice: run_graph:        ==== Transition 65 (Complete=1, Pending=0, Fired=0, Skipped=0, Incomplete=0, Source=/var/lib/pengine/pe-input-68.bz2): Complete
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1894] clustera       crmd:   notice: do_state_transition:      State transition S_TRANSITION_ENGINE -> S_POLICY_ENGINE [ input=I_PE_CALC cause=C_FSA_INTERNAL origin=notify_crmd ]
Apr 28 12:41:18 [1892] clustera      attrd:   notice: attrd_trigger_update:     Sending flush op to all hosts for: fail-count-POSTGRESQL:0 (14)
```

My pacemaker configuration is as follows :

```
node clustera attributes standby="off"
node clusterb attributes standby="off"
primitive POSTGRESQL ocf:xxx:postgresql \
    params repmgr_conf="/var/lib/pgsql/repmgr/repmgr.conf" pgctl="/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_ctl" pgdata="/opt/pgdata" \
    op start interval="0" timeout="90s" \
    op stop interval="0" timeout="60s" \
    op promote interval="0" timeout="120s" \
    op monitor interval="53s" role="Master" \
    op monitor interval="60s" role="Slave"
ms MS_POSTGRESQL POSTGRESQL \
    meta clone-max="2" target-role="Started" resource-stickiness="100" notify="true"
property $id="cib-bootstrap-options" \
    dc-version="1.1.7-6.el6-148fccfd5985c5590cc601123c6c16e966b85d14" \
    cluster-infrastructure="openais" \
    expected-quorum-votes="2" \
    stonith-enabled="false" \
    no-quorum-policy="ignore" \
    default-resource-stickiness="10" \
    start-failure-is-fatal="false" \
    last-lrm-refresh="1398700283"
```

My postgresql resource agent is as follows (inspired by https://github.com/xmm/repmgr) :

```
OCF_ROOT=/usr/lib/ocf
OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE="pg92"

: ${OCF_FUNCTIONS_DIR=${OCF_ROOT}/resource.d/heartbeat}
. ${OCF_FUNCTIONS_DIR}/.ocf-shellfuncs

: ${OCF_RESKEY_CRM_meta_clone_node_max=1}
: ${OCF_RESKEY_CRM_meta_master_max=1}
: ${OCF_RESKEY_CRM_meta_master_node_max=1}

: ${OCF_RESKEY_PG_ROOT=/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin}
: ${OCF_RESKEY_repmgr=${OCF_RESKEY_PG_ROOT}/repmgr}
: ${OCF_RESKEY_repmgr_conf=/var/lib/pgsql/repmgr/repmgr.conf}
: ${OCF_RESKEY_repmgr_clone_opt="-d postgres -U repmgr -R postgres"}

: ${OCF_RESKEY_pgctl=${OCF_RESKEY_PG_ROOT}/pg_ctl}
: ${OCF_RESKEY_psql=${OCF_RESKEY_PG_ROOT}/psql}
: ${OCF_RESKEY_pgdata=/opt/pgdata}
: ${OCF_RESKEY_pgconfig=${OCF_RESKEY_pgdata}/postgresql.conf}
: ${OCF_RESKEY_pgdba=postgres}
: ${OCF_RESKEY_pgport=5432}
: ${OCF_RESKEY_start_opt="-p $OCF_RESKEY_pgport"}
: ${OCF_RESKEY_pgdb=pgbench}
: ${OCF_RESKEY_logfile=/var/ha/postgresql/postgres_ha.log}
: ${OCF_RESKEY_stop_escalate=30}
: ${OCF_RESKEY_master_score=100}
: ${OCF_RESKEY_slave_score=50}

: ${OCF_RESKEY_STATUS_ISREPLICATION_SQL="SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();"}

CRM_MASTER="${HA_SBIN_DIR}/crm_master -l reboot"
PIDFILE=${OCF_RESKEY_pgdata}/postmaster.pid
SOCKETDIR=/var/run/postgresql

meta_data() {
    cat <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE resource-agent SYSTEM "ra-api-1.dtd">
<resource-agent name="pgsql" version="1.0">
<version>1.0</version>

<longdesc lang="en">
Master/Slave OCF Resource Agent for PostgreSQL with Hot, Warm or Streaming Backup
</longdesc>
<shortdesc lang="en">Manages a PostgreSQL Master/Slave instance</shortdesc>

<parameters>
<parameter name="repmgr" unique="0" required="0">
<longdesc lang="en">
Path to repmgr command.
</longdesc>
<shortdesc lang="en">repmgr</shortdesc>
<content type="string" default="/usr/bin/repmgr" />
</parameter>

<parameter name="repmgr_conf" unique="0" required="0">
<longdesc lang="en">
Path to repmgr config file.
</longdesc>
<shortdesc lang="en">repmgr_conf</shortdesc>
<content type="string" default="/var/lib/pgsql/data" />
</parameter>

<parameter name="repmgr_clone_opt" unique="0" required="0">
<longdesc lang="en">
standby clone params for repmgr command.
</longdesc>
<shortdesc lang="en">repmgr_clone_opt</shortdesc>
<content type="string" default="-d postgres -U repmgr -R postgres" />
</parameter>

<parameter name="pgctl" unique="0" required="0">
<longdesc lang="en">
Path to pg_ctl command.
</longdesc>
<shortdesc lang="en">pgctl</shortdesc>
<content type="string" default="/usr/bin/pg_ctl" />
</parameter>

<parameter name="start_opt" unique="0" required="0">
<longdesc lang="en">
Start options (-o start_opt in pgi_ctl). "-i -p 5432" for example.
</longdesc>
<shortdesc lang="en">start_opt</shortdesc>
<content type="string" default="" />
</parameter>

<parameter name="ctl_opt" unique="0" required="0">
<longdesc lang="en">
Additional pg_ctl options. Default is ""
</longdesc>
<shortdesc lang="en">ctl_opt</shortdesc>
<content type="string" default="" />
</parameter>

<parameter name="psql" unique="0" required="0">
<longdesc lang="en">
Path to psql command.
</longdesc>
<shortdesc lang="en">psql</shortdesc>
<content type="string" default="/usr/bin/psql" />
</parameter>

<parameter name="pgdata" unique="0" required="0">
<longdesc lang="en">
Path to PostgreSQL data directory.
</longdesc>
<shortdesc lang="en">pgdata</shortdesc>
<content type="string" default="/var/lib/pgsql/data" />
</parameter>

<parameter name="pgdba" unique="0" required="0">
<longdesc lang="en">
User that owns PostgreSQL.
</longdesc>
<shortdesc lang="en">pgdba</shortdesc>
<content type="string" default="postgres" />
</parameter>

<parameter name="pghost" unique="0" required="0">
<longdesc lang="en">
Hostname/IP Addreess where PosrgeSQL is listening
</longdesc>
<shortdesc lang="en">pghost</shortdesc>
<content type="string" default="" />
</parameter>

<parameter name="pgport" unique="0" required="0">
<longdesc lang="en">
Port where PosrgeSQL is listening
</longdesc>
<shortdesc lang="en">pgport</shortdesc>
<content type="string" default="5432" />
</parameter>

<parameter name="pgdb" unique="0" required="0">
<longdesc lang="en">
Database that will be used for monitoring.
</longdesc>
<shortdesc lang="en">pgdb</shortdesc>
<content type="string" default="template1" />
</parameter>

<parameter name="logfile" unique="0" required="0">
<longdesc lang="en">
Path to PostgreSQL server log output file.
</longdesc>
<shortdesc lang="en">logfile</shortdesc>
<content type="string" default="/dev/null" />
</parameter>

<parameter name="stop_escalate" unique="0" required="0">
<longdesc lang="en">
Number of retries (using -m fast) before resorting to -m immediate
</longdesc>
<shortdesc lang="en">stop escalation</shortdesc>
<content type="string" default="30" />
</parameter>

<parameter name="master_score" unique="0" required="0">
<longdesc lang="en">
Score for adding to node with master instance
</longdesc>
<shortdesc lang="en">master_score</shortdesc>
<content type="string" default="100" />
</parameter>

<parameter name="slave_score" unique="0" required="0">
<longdesc lang="en">
Score for adding to node with slave instance
</longdesc>
<shortdesc lang="en">slave_score</shortdesc>
<content type="string" default="50" />
</parameter>

</parameters>

<actions>
<action name="start"   timeout="90" />
<action name="promote"   timeout="90" />
<action name="demote"   timeout="90" />
<action name="stop"    timeout="60" />
<action name="notify"   timeout="20" />
<action name="monitor" depth="0"  timeout="20" interval="20" role="Slave"/>
<action name="monitor" depth="0"  timeout="20" interval="10" role="Master"/>
<action name="meta-data"  timeout="5" />
<action name="validate-all"  timeout="20" />
</actions>
</resource-agent>
EOF
    exit $OCF_SUCCESS
}

log_params()
{
    ocf_log info "ACTION=$__OCF_ACTION"
    for param in `env | grep OCF | sort`
    do 
        ocf_log info "$param"
    done
}

meta_expect()
{
    local what=$1 whatvar=OCF_RESKEY_CRM_meta_${1//-/_} op=$2 expect=$3
    local val=${!whatvar}
    if [[ -n $val ]]; then
        # [, not [[, or it won't work ;)
        [ $val $op $expect ] && return
    fi
    ocf_log err "meta parameter misconfigured, expected $what $op $expect, but found ${val:-unset}."
    exit $OCF_ERR_CONFIGURED
}

check_config() {
    if [ ! -r "$1" ] ; then
        ocf_log err "Setup problem: Couldn't find config file $1"
        exit $OCF_ERR_INSTALLED
    fi
}

get_node_status () {
        ocf_log info "Getting node status: "
        output_health=`${OCF_RESKEY_psql} -U $OCF_RESKEY_pgdba -d $OCF_RESKEY_pgdb -Atc "SELECT 1=1;" |grep "t"`
    rc=$?
        if [ $rc -eq 0 ]; then
            ocf_log info "[Healthcheck] Node is running fine"
        else
            ocf_log info "[Healthcheck] Node is down"
            return 6
        fi

        output_slave=`${OCF_RESKEY_psql} -U $OCF_RESKEY_pgdba -d $OCF_RESKEY_pgdb -Atc "SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();" |grep "t"`
        rc=$?
        if [ $rc -eq 0 ]; then
            ocf_log info "[Node status] SLAVE"
            return 0
        else
            ocf_log info "[Node status] MASTER"
            return 100
        fi
}

run_as_pg() {
    ocf_log info "Run as $OCF_RESKEY_pgdba: $@"
    output=`su - $OCF_RESKEY_pgdba -c "$*" 2>&1`
    rc=$?
    output=`echo $output`
    if [ $rc -eq 0 ]; then 
        if [ ! -z "$output" ]; then
            ocf_log info "$output"
        fi
        return $OCF_SUCCESS
    else
        if [ ! -z "$output" ]; then
            ocf_log err "$output"
        else
            ocf_log err "command failed: $*"
        fi
        return $OCF_ERR_GENERIC
    fi
}

pg_check_pid() {
    if [ -f $PIDFILE ]
    then
        PID=`head -n 1 $PIDFILE`
        kill -0 $PID >/dev/null 2>&1 && fuser $OCF_RESKEY_pgdata 2>&1 | grep $PID >/dev/null 2>&1
        return $?
    fi
    false
}

run_repmgr() {
    # pgctl should be in PATH (set it in /etc/login.defs or ~postgres/.profile)
    ocf_log info "Run as $OCF_RESKEY_pgdba: ${OCF_RESKEY_repmgr} $@"
    su --login $OCF_RESKEY_pgdba -c "${OCF_RESKEY_repmgr} $*" 2>&1 >> /dev/r.out
    rc=$?
    # 100 = master state
    if [ $rc -ne 0 -a $rc -ne 100 ]; then 
        ocf_log err "command failed: ${OCF_RESKEY_repmgr} $*"
    fi
    return $rc
}

pg_state_check() {
    local status
    if ! pg_check_pid
    then
        return $OCF_NOT_RUNNING
    else
        ocf_log info "PostgreSQL proccess exist..."
    fi


    get_node_status
    status=$?
echo "in pg_state_check: $status"

    case $status in
        0)   return $OCF_SUCCESS ;;
        100) return $OCF_RUNNING_MASTER ;;
        6|7) rc=$OCF_NOT_RUNNING ;; # ERR_DB_CON, ERR_DB_QUERY
        1|9) rc=$OCF_ERR_INSTALLED ;; # ERR_BAD_CONFIG, ERR_BAD_PASSWORD
        *)  # TODO: Is it need to return OCF_ERR_CONFIGURED for full shutdown of the resource?
            ocf_log err "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE}: UNEXPECTED repmgr error ($status)!!!"
            rc=$status ;;
    esac
    return $rc
}

pg_start() {
    mkdir -p $SOCKETDIR &&  \
    chown $OCF_RESKEY_pgdba. $SOCKETDIR && \
    chmod 2775 $SOCKETDIR
echo starting ${OCF_RESKEY_pgctl} start -w -D ${OCF_RESKEY_pgdata} $OCF_RESKEY_ctl_opt -l ${OCF_RESKEY_logfile} -o "'-c config_file=${OCF_RESKEY_pgconfig}'" -o "'$OCF_RESKEY_start_opt'"
    run_as_pg ${OCF_RESKEY_pgctl} start -w -D ${OCF_RESKEY_pgdata} $OCF_RESKEY_ctl_opt -l ${OCF_RESKEY_logfile} -o "'-c config_file=${OCF_RESKEY_pgconfig}'" -o "'$OCF_RESKEY_start_opt'"
echo "pg_start(): asked for start , waiting 10s"
    sleep 10
echo "pg_start(): asked for start, waited long enough"
}

pg_stop() {
    local status
    run_as_pg ${OCF_RESKEY_pgctl} stop -m fast -D ${OCF_RESKEY_pgdata} -l ${OCF_RESKEY_logfile} -o "'-c config_file=${OCF_RESKEY_pgconfig}'"
    # stop waiting
    count=0
    while [ $count -lt $OCF_RESKEY_stop_escalate ]
    do
        pg_state_check
        status=$?
        if [ "$status" -eq $OCF_NOT_RUNNING ]; then
            #PostgreSQL stopped
            break;
        fi
        count=`expr $count + 1`
        sleep 1
    done

    if pg_check_pid
    then
        #PostgreSQL is still up. Use another shutdown mode.
        ocf_log info "PostgreSQL failed to stop after ${OCF_RESKEY_stop_escalate}s using -m fast. Trying -m immediate..."
        run_as_pg ${OCF_RESKEY_pgctl} stop -w -m immediate -D ${OCF_RESKEY_pgdata} -l ${OCF_RESKEY_logfile} -o "'-c config_file=${OCF_RESKEY_pgconfig}'"
        while :
        do
            pg_check_pid || break
            sleep 1
            ocf_log debug "PostgreSQL still hasn't stopped yet. Waiting..."
        done
    fi

    rm -f $PIDFILE
    ocf_log info "PostgreSQL is stopped"
    return $OCF_SUCCESS
}

pg_promote() {
    local status
    run_repmgr -f ${OCF_RESKEY_repmgr_conf} --verbose --force standby promote
    status=$?
    case $status in
        0) return $OCF_SUCCESS ;;
        6|7) rc=$OCF_NOT_RUNNING ;; # ERR_DB_CON, ERR_DB_QUERY
        1|9) rc=$OCF_ERR_INSTALLED ;; # ERR_BAD_CONFIG, ERR_BAD_PASSWORD
        4) rc=$OCF_ERR_GENERIC ;; # ERR_NO_RESTART
        *) rc=$OCF_ERR_GENERIC ;;
    esac
    ocf_log err "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE}: Promoting failed ($status)"
    return $rc
}

pg_follow_master() {
    run_repmgr -f ${OCF_RESKEY_repmgr_conf} standby follow
}

pg_clone_master() {
    run_repmgr -D ${OCF_RESKEY_pgdata} ${OCF_RESKEY_repmgr_clone_opt} --force standby clone $1 || return $OCF_ERR_INSTALLED
}

pg_demote() {
    new_master=$1
    run_repmgr --verbose standby clone $new_master 
}

rename_data() {
    if [ -d ${OCF_RESKEY_pgdata} ]; then
        new_name="`dirname ${OCF_RESKEY_pgdata}`/`basename ${OCF_RESKEY_pgdata}`-`date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S`"
        if [ -d $new_name ] ; then
            new_name="`dirname ${OCF_RESKEY_pgdata}`/`basename ${OCF_RESKEY_pgdata}`-`date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S-%N`"
        fi

        if mv ${OCF_RESKEY_pgdata} $new_name ; then
            ocf_log info "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} Data dir ${OCF_RESKEY_pgdata} saved as $new_name"
        else
            ocf_log err "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} Cannot rename data dir ${OCF_RESKEY_pgdata} to $new_name"
            return $OCF_ERR_INSTALLED
        fi
    fi
}

pgsql_start() {
    local status
    ocf_log info "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE}: Starting"
    pg_state_check
    status=$? 
echo "START: status = $status"

    case "$status" in
        $OCF_RUNNING_MASTER)
echo "start() RUNNING MASTER"
            ocf_log warn "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} already started as Primary."
            ;;
        $OCF_SUCCESS)
echo "start() SUCCESS"
            ocf_log warn "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} already started as Standby."
            ;;
        $OCF_NOT_RUNNING)
echo "start() NOT RUNNING"
            log_params
            # $OCF_RESKEY_CRM_meta_notify_master_uname can be ' '
            if [ "$OCF_RESKEY_CRM_meta_notify_master_uname" != ' ' -a "$OCF_RESKEY_CRM_meta_notify_master_uname" != '`$HOSTNAME`' ] ; then
echo "XXX"
                ocf_log info "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} Master instance exist on host ${OCF_RESKEY_CRM_meta_notify_master_uname}" 
                if [ ! -f ${OCF_RESKEY_pgdata}/recovery.conf ] ; then
echo "no reconvery.conf"
                    ocf_log warn "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} recovery.conf file not found. I think this is old Master. Start cloning the current Master..." 
                    rename_data &&
                        pg_clone_master $OCF_RESKEY_CRM_meta_notify_master_uname ||
                            return $?
                fi
            fi
echo "calling pg_start"
            pg_start
echo "checing state"
            pg_state_check
            status=$?
            if [ "$status" = $OCF_RUNNING_MASTER ] ; then
echo "started as MASTER"
                ocf_log warn "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} started as Master"
            elif [ "$status" = $OCF_SUCCESS ] ; then
echo "started as STANDBY"
                ocf_log info "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} started as Standby"
            else
echo "unexpected status $status"
                ocf_log err "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} Unexpected status ($status) of node at start action"
                return $status
            fi
            ;;
        *)
            ocf_log err "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} Unexpected status ($status) of node at start action"
            #$CRM_MASTER -D
            return $status
            ;;
    esac
    $CRM_MASTER -v ${OCF_RESKEY_slave_score}
    return $OCF_SUCCESS
}

pgsql_promote() {
    local status
    ocf_log info "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE}: Promoting"
    pg_state_check 
    status=$? 
    case "$status" in
        $OCF_RUNNING_MASTER)
            ocf_log warn "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} already started as Primary."
            ;;
        $OCF_SUCCESS)
            pg_promote
            status=$?
            if [ $status = $OCF_RUNNING_MASTER ] ; then
                ocf_log warn "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} started as Primary."
            else
                #$CRM_MASTER -D
                return $status
            fi
            ;;
        $OCF_NOT_RUNNING)
            #$CRM_MASTER -D
            return $status
            ;;
        *)
            ocf_log err "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} Unexpected status ($status) of node at promote action."
            #$CRM_MASTER -D
            return $status
    esac
    $CRM_MASTER -v ${OCF_RESKEY_master_score}
    return $OCF_SUCCESS
}

pgsql_demote() {
    # We cannot switch to standby if another master not started yet
    local status
    ocf_log info "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE}: Demoting"
    $CRM_MASTER -D
    pg_state_check
    status=$? 
    case "$status" in
        $OCF_RUNNING_MASTER)
            log_params
            pg_stop
            pg_state_check
            status=$?
            if [ "$status" = $OCF_NOT_RUNNING ] ; then
                return $OCF_SUCCESS
            elif [ "$status" = $OCF_RUNNING_MASTER -o "$status" = $OCF_SUCCESS ] ; then
                ocf_log warn "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} Cannot stop resource, still runned"
                return $OCF_ERR_GENERIC
            fi
            return $OCF_SUCCESS
            ;;
        $OCF_SUCCESS)
            ocf_log warn "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} already Standby."
            return $OCF_SUCCESS
            ;;
        $OCF_NOT_RUNNING)
            ocf_log err "Trying to demote a resource that was not started"
            return $OCF_NOT_RUNNING
            ;;
        *)
            ocf_log err "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} Unexpected status ($status) of node at demote action. Score will removed"
            ;;
    esac
    return $status
}

pgsql_stop() {
    local status
    ocf_log info "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE}: Stopping"
    $CRM_MASTER -D
    pg_state_check
    status=$? 
    case "$status" in
        $OCF_RUNNING_MASTER | $OCF_SUCCESS)
            pg_stop
            pg_state_check
            status=$?
            if [ "$status" = $OCF_NOT_RUNNING ] ; then
                return $OCF_SUCCESS
            elif [ "$status" = $OCF_RUNNING_MASTER -o "$status" = $OCF_SUCCESS ] ; then
                ocf_log warn "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} Cannot stop resource, still runned"
                return $OCF_ERR_GENERIC
            fi
            ;;
        $OCF_NOT_RUNNING)
            ocf_log err "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} Trying to stop a resource that was not started"
            return $OCF_SUCCESS
            ;;
        *)
            ocf_log err "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} Unexpected status ($status) of node at stop action. Score will removed"
            ;;
    esac
    return $status
}

pgsql_monitor() {
    local status
    pg_state_check
    status=$? 
echo "pg_state_check returned $status"

    case "$status" in
        $OCF_RUNNING_MASTER)
echo ">>>>>> MASTER"
echo $CRM_MASTER
echo $CRM_MASTER -v ${OCF_RESKEY_master_score}

            ocf_log info "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} PostgreSQL in Master mode"
            $CRM_MASTER -v ${OCF_RESKEY_master_score}
            ;;
        $OCF_SUCCESS)
echo ">>>>>> SLAVE"
            ocf_log info "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} PostgreSQL in Standby mode"
            $CRM_MASTER -v ${OCF_RESKEY_slave_score}
            ;;
        $OCF_NOT_RUNNING)
echo ">>>>>> NOT RUNNING"
            ocf_log info "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} PostgreSQL is not runned"
            $CRM_MASTER -D
            ;;
        *)
            ocf_log err "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE} Unexpected status ($status)"
            $CRM_MASTER -D
            ;;
    esac
    return $status
}

pgsql_validate_all() {
    meta_expect master-max -le 1
    meta_expect clone-node-max = 1
    meta_expect master-node-max = 1
echo "UNAME  === ${OCF_RESKEY_CRM_meta_notify_start_uname}"

    if [ $__OCF_ACTION != "monitor" -a "${OCF_RESKEY_CRM_meta_notify_start_uname- NOT SET }" = " NOT SET " ]; then
        ocf_log err "you should enable notify when using this RA"
        log_params
echo "ERR CONFIGURED in VALIDATE ALL"
        return $OCF_ERR_CONFIGURED
    fi

    check_binary fuser
    check_binary $OCF_RESKEY_pgctl
    check_binary $OCF_RESKEY_psql
    check_binary $OCF_RESKEY_repmgr
    check_config $OCF_RESKEY_pgconfig
    check_config $OCF_RESKEY_repmgr_conf

    if ! su --login $OCF_RESKEY_pgdba -c "type -p `basename $OCF_RESKEY_pgctl`" > /dev/null ; then
        ocf_log err "`basename $OCF_RESKEY_pgctl` should be in PATH for user $OCF_RESKEY_pgdba"
        return $OCF_ERR_INSTALLED
    fi
echo "SUCCESS"  
    return $OCF_SUCCESS
}

pgsql_notify() {
    local n_type=$OCF_RESKEY_CRM_meta_notify_type
    local n_op=$OCF_RESKEY_CRM_meta_notify_operation

    # post/promote: slave follow new master

    ocf_log info "${OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE}: NOTIFY $n_type/$n_op"
    #log_params
    return $OCF_SUCCESS
}

pgsql_usage() {
    cat <<END
usage: $0 {start|stop|promote|demote|monitor|validate-all|meta-data}

Expects to have a fully populated OCF RA-compliant environment set.
END
    exit $1
}

#######################################################################
### Main ###

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    usage
    exit $OCF_ERR_ARGS
fi

case $__OCF_ACTION in
    meta-data)
        meta_data
        exit $OCF_SUCCESS;;
    usage|help)
        pgsql_usage $OCF_SUCCESS;;
esac

pgsql_validate_all || exit
echo "POSTGRESQL : action = $__OCF_ACTION"

case $__OCF_ACTION in
    start)      pgsql_start;;
    promote)    pgsql_promote;;
    demote)     pgsql_demote;;
    stop)       pgsql_stop;;
    notify)     pgsql_notify;;
    monitor)    pgsql_monitor;;
    validate-all) ;;
    *)          pgsql_usage $OCF_ERR_UNIMPLEMENTED;;
esac

exit
```

Any clue ?

Comment: Note, copied from http://stackoverflow.com/q/23352438/398670 after suggestion to move to serverfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the resource agent, the following should not appear :

OCF_ROOT=/usr/lib/ocf
OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE="pg92"

These were intended to debug the script manually by starting it by hand and forcing the OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE variable.

This solved the issue.